# testing app on my phone made in eclipse

Tags: android, windows, driver

I have a problem, while following the instuctions at: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html I get redirected to this list: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers.

Where it says "The Galaxy Nexus driver, however, is distributed by Samsung (listed as model SCH-I515)."

Im using a galaxy nexus and a Dell laptop (Windows 7, 64), Ive talked to both swedish and english support and none of them knew how to find this driver.

Dont really know where else to ask this so Im hoping someone here has done this before and knows how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% positive I understand what your asking because I may have found this a little too quickly.  Upon following the instructions that you followed, I ended up at this website.  [Galaxy Nexus](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW).  I clicked "**See All Downloads**" below "**Downloads**", and then clicked "**Software**" where I found **Device(Install),USB Driver (Software) (ver.1.4.6.0)**.

Comment: this looks right, dows it matter that I dont use verizon? cus the file-name I get starts with Verizon :P

Comment: It shouldn't matter since its distributed by Samsung, and the android website is what led us there.

Comment: I downloaded it and it installed to programfiles/SAMSUNG/Usb-drivers. My phone installed it. the next sted says to run "adb-devices" in my platform-tools directory, but I dont have that file, just a file labeled "adb" and some other stuff.. Im not presented with the "Device chooser" in Eclipse when I run either. using this guide: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: actually shift+right click -> open command window -> adb devices, worked! It found the serial number of my phone. Still dont know hot to open the app on my phone tho

Comment: For the "Device chooser" part you should be able to do the following:
Right Click Project --> Run as --> Run Configurations --> Target.
I believe this is what your referring too.  I also don't have the "adb-devices".  I personally haven't set up an actual hardware emulator yet.

Comment: I just saw your comment so please refer to the above, and ignore the "adb-devices" part.